# What permission allows removing dashlets from "Configure Your Dashboard"?

Tags: permissions, dashboard, dashlet

As an admistrator, if I hover over a draggable dashlet title in the "Configure My Dashboard" view, I get a little cross that I can click and I can remove the dashlet from everybody's dashboard.

I want to give this permission to another user but I gave him all the report-related permissions and this still does not work for him. Is there a permission that I can give him or does it just check for the "Admin" role?